# sh sudo string parameter

Tags: command-line, sudo, sh

I'm playing with my Raspberry Pi Zero, and I'm trying to automate an FM transmitter script.

You can run the script with `sudo fm_transmitter -f [frequency] -r [.wav music file]`

For example:

```
sudo fm_transmitter -f 103 -r star_wars.wav
```

My code:

```
musics[0] = "/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav"

sudo /home/pi/radio/fm/fm_transmitter -f 103 -r musics[0]
```

It gives me an error because it can't find `musics[0]`.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is this a Bash script or a strictly `sh` script?  Arrays are a Bash thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `music[0]`, is that an array?

Comment: i want to feed in that star_wars.wav file into -r
so i can change it when it finishes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've set the first element of an array as `/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav` with the line:

```
musics[0]="/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav"
```

To access the contents, you need to expand that array element using `$` like so:

```
sudo /home/pi/radio/fm/fm_transmitter -f 103 -r "${musics[0]}"
```

The quotes `""` are used to preserve the format of the output, and the braces `{}` are part of expanding an array variable.

It's not clear why you're using an array here, when a standard variable would work. You could replace:

```
musics[0]="/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav"
```

with

```
musics="/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav"
```

and the line using that variable changes to:

```
sudo /home/pi/radio/fm/fm_transmitter -f 103 -r "$musics"
```

This is much simpler as you don't need to use index numbers (the part referred to by [0]).

Comment: i tried ``echo "${musics[0]}"`` and adding it into the sudo method, but it just says it cant find musics[0](even the echo)

Comment: i want to use an array so i can switch songs when they ended

Comment: If there are spaces around the `=` in the first line, the variable won't be assigned. Are you using the Bash shell?

Comment: + it says that musics[0] is not found and i an using bash

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces around the `=`, if it says it can't find `musics[0]` then it is trying to find the literal string 'musics[0]', which means that you're not trying to expand the variable at all. There is no need to add an echo command into the `sudo fm_transmitter ...` command.

Comment: Try this on its own with no other code:
`musics[0]="/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav" ; echo "${musics[0]}"`
The result should be `/home/pi/radio/fm/star_wars.wav`

Comment: It does wotk that way, but it doesnt in the script

Comment: @BurgerlX are you sure you are executing the script with bash (not for example `dash`/`sh` - which doesn't provide arrays)?

Comment: i am...

somerandomshitsoicanpostthissss

Comment: If you're using the lines exactly as I've written them, and getting the error message `cannot find musics[0]` then there must be some typo in the script somewhere. Probably around the part where you expand the variable, are you missing the `$`?